# move_uploaded_file not working, no error

Tags: php

I have to make a website for school and i want to be able to upload pictures. the move_uploaded_file() function is not working and i don't know why, paths are both correct (i show them with an echo) : \ annd not /, there's the file's name in the move_uploaded_file(), the directory creates successfully but i can't get the picture in it :/

Here's my code :

```
                   if(isset($_POST["submitted"]))
                   {
                     if ($_FILES['imgWork']['error'] > 0) 
                    {
                        $erreur = "Erreur lors du transfert"; //Vérification
                        echo $erreur;
                        if($_FILES['imgWork']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)
                        {
                            $erreurDetail = "fichier manquant."; //Vérification
                            echo $erreurDetail;
                        }
                        if($_FILES['imgWork']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE)
                        {
                            $erreurDetail = "fichier dépassant la taille maximale autorisée par PHP."; //Vérification
                            echo $erreurDetail;
                        }
                        if($_FILES['imgWork']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE)
                        {
                            $erreurDetail = "fichier dépassant la taille maximale autorisée par le formulaire."; //Vérification
                            echo $erreurDetail;
                        }
                        if($_FILES['imgWork']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL)
                        {
                            $erreurDetail = "Partiel"; //Vérification
                            echo $erreurDetail;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        $tmp = $_FILES['imgWork']['tmp_name'];
                        $servRoot = str_replace("/",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]); // adaptation du chemin racine serveur
                        $dossierWork= $servRoot.'siteOk'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'img'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'worksTest'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                        //Créer un dossier
                        if(!file_exists($dossierWork))
                            mkdir($dossierWork, 0777, true);
                        //1. strrchr renvoie l'extension avec le point (« . »).
                        //2. substr(chaine,1) ignore le premier caractère de chaine.
                        //3. strtolower met l'extension en minuscules.
                        $ext = strtolower(  substr(  strrchr($_FILES['imgWork']['name'], '.')  ,1)  );
                        $nom = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)); //Nom random du fichier
                        $path = $dossierWork.$nom.'.'.$ext; //Chemin du fichier avec nom random et extension en partant de la racine du serveur.

                        $resultat = move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path);
                        if ($resultat) 
                        {
                            $transfert='<span style="color: green;">Transfert réussi</span>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $transfert='<span style="color: red;">Echec du transfert</span>';
                        }

                        echo $tmp.'<br>';
                        echo $path.'<br>';
                        echo $ext.'<br>';                           
                        echo $nom.'<br>';
                    }
```

}

Here's the form :

```
                        <form method="post" action="index.php#addWorks" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Ajouter un travail</legend>     
                                <label>Titre* :<input type="text" name="titre_form" /></label><br> 
                                <label>Description* :<input type="text" name="description_form" /></label><br>
                                <label>Signature* :<input type="text" name="signature_form" /></label><br>
                                <input type="file" name="imgWork" /> <br>
                                <?php
                                    if(isset($_POST["submitted"]))
                                    {
                                        echo $transfert.'<br>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                                Graphisme<input type="radio" name="type" value="graphisme" checked class="radio"/><br>
                                3D<input type="radio" name="type" value="3d" class="radio"/><br>
                                Web<input type="radio" name="type" value="web" class="radio"/><br>

                        </fieldset>
                        <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Envoyer" />
                    </form>
```

It only writes "echec du transfert" so i guess it's the move_uploaded_file.

How can i make it work?

Thank you :)

Edit : It may be usefull to specify i'm using WampServer on windows 8 :)

Comment: `$_FILES['image']` - *ahem*. Plus, this is invalid `770`. Then check for folder's permissions.

Comment: Yes sorry i deleted it ^^ It was a paste from the internet and i forgot to delete it :p Still not working anyway :( Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Plus, what's this `action="index.php#addWorks"`? There's no id of that name and you shouldn't be using that anyway. Hashtags don't work with PHP, far as I know.

Comment: It was a try to stay there when the form is submitted ^^ But i made a little script and let it there (i know, i'm trying a lot of things so it's sometimes weird :p) but doesn't change anything neither :)

Comment: Also check to see what your max upload size are in your `.ini` files. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: error display is on?

Comment: What I don't get is this `if(isset($_POST["submitted"]))
                                    {
                                        echo $transfert.'<br>';
                                    }` you're just echoing `$transfert`. Your uploading code should be in there.

Comment: Still no error :( Btw a print_r($_FILES) :     Array ( [imgWork] => Array ( [name] => Drapeau.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => D:\Programmes\Logiciels\wamp\tmp\php3DD.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 7547 ) ) So i guess there's no size problem :/

Comment: Well actually, my uploading code is in the same if but there's a lot of useless things in it too (essentially mysql). I only wanted to put the $transfert in the form :)

Comment: Is the folder writeable? Meaning, does your script have permission to write to the folder?

Comment: isWritable returns true so i guess it's writable

Comment: No you have to go check the actual permissions. As far as I recall, you can't trust php's isWritable on Windows : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27609

Comment: My wamp directory is on "read only" but i don't know how to change it :/ When i uncheck the box and apply, it comes back to checked :(

Comment: You might want to look at your Apache log files to see if there is anything useful there.

Comment: [Tue Dec 16 03:42:41 2014] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: D:/Programmes/Logiciels/wamp/www/SiteOk/aaa, referer: http://localhost/SiteOk/index.php I don't know what happens, there's no aaa in my code :/